# How do I render a grid only on the last page in BIRT?

Tags: java, birt

Using BIRT 3.7.2, I'm trying to place a grid at the bottom part of the last page of a report for signatories. However I can't seem to find a way to do that.

I've tried to place the grid in a footer and render it using:

```
if(BirtComp.lessThan(pageNumber, totalPage)) { 
    this.getStyle().display = "none"; 
}
```

on the grid's onRender.
However this only works on the webviewer, and I need it to work in PDF with my Java application. When I use run and format=pdf parameters, there is still that grid at every page, and using frameset instead of run makes it not appear at all. Are there other techniques to do this? If else I may have to settle for placing the signatory grid below the table data so at least it will be on the last page.

Comment: It should work on the last page using frameset. Is the report Layout property set to "auto" or "fixed"? Anyway to make it work your java application should not use a RunAndRender task, but a run task and then a render task instead.